# Correct way to call XML-RPC service from an EJB

Tags: multithreading, glassfish, ejb, xml-rpc

I've got a Stateless EJB that needs to update another website using XML-RPC.  I've been using the Apache XML-RPC Client (http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/). It has been working fine, but after the method of called several times the whole application server (GlassFish v2.2) locks up and I need to kill the server to get it to respond again.

After extensive reading, I believe it is caused by some thread manipulating in the XML-RPC client, since thread manipulation is not recommended in EJB.

I am just wondering, how is one supposed to call external services (such as an XML-RPC service) in an EJB to be completely safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not related to the Apache XML-RPC client, but a memory allocation / garbage collection misconfiguration.